# How can I make py.test print stack traces for test failures / errors as they happen?

Tags: python, pytest

Default behaviour is to wait until the whole test suite is complete before printing out all the stack traces. I can't seem to find an option to print out the stack traces as each test completes. `-s` doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout [pytest-instafail](https://github.com/jpvanhal/pytest-instafail). :)

Comment: Also pytest-sugar for another take on this.

Comment: These are both beautiful :)